# Is the syntax in this piece of python code correct?

Tags: python

I've just started learning python for a university course. Were using the book "Exploratory programming for the arts and humanities" by Nick Montfort. In one of the first chapters he presents the code for a program that won't execute. Since he is using it as an explanatory example I really need it to work to be able to get past the chapter in the book.

I've tried both with python 3 and python 2, but keep getting the message "incorrect syntax" in line 1.

```
def double([1, 10, 5]): 
    result = [] #here starts the function body
    for element in sequence:
        result = result + [element * 2]
    return result
```

It's supposed to double the value of the number input within the brackets, but it seems like using both parenthesis and brackets in the function name causes problem. However, that is how it's written in the book.
Has the author made a mistake in the code or is this code executable in an older version of python perhaps?
Very thankful for help!

Comment: Looks like either they meant to initialize the function with a default value and forgot to name the input parameter, or they mixed up defining the function and calling the function

Comment: You need to have argument name. Try this `def double(sequence=[1, 10, 5]): ` instead of `def double([1, 10, 5]):`

Comment: `#here starts the function body` is not only a useless comment, it's worst: it's wrong. The function body started before the declaration of `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the book, I'm afraid. Looking at the [Google books preview of the chapter](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0BXvCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false), I can see that the author gives you the function correctly.

On [page 45](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0BXvCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false) (the first page of Chapter 3, *Double, Double!*), the function is defined as:

```
def double(sequence):
    result = []
    for element in sequence:
        result = result + [element * 2]
    return result
```

and on [page 48](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0BXvCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false) (in the section headed *3.1 Trying Out the Function*), the author *calls* the function, by using the name (`double`) followed directly by a call expression (parentheses and the values for each parameter):

```
double([1, 10, 5])
```

This tells Python to execute the body of the `double` function with `sequence` set to `[1, 10, 5]`.

You seem to have combined the two pieces of syntax. You replaced the `sequence` parameter name in the `def double(....): ...` function definition syntax with the list itself. That's not quite how it works, a function definition has *parameters* that the caller must provide values for, but parameters are not themselves expressions.

If you wanted to replace the `sequence` parameter in the function, then you could remove the parameter altogether, and just assign the list inside the function body:

```
def double():
    sequence = [1, 10, 5]
    result = []
    for element in sequence:
        result = result + [element * 2]
    return result
```

This version of the function takes arguments, only `double()` would work. This is not nearly as useful!

On a side note: The book you are using teaches the Python 2 syntax, a revision of the  language that'll very soon be obsolete. The end of the line is Python 2.7, which [reaches it's end of life in a few months time](https://pythonclock.org/).

If you wanted to find a more up-to-date alternative, I recommend you look at [Think Python, 2nd edition](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/), which is available in paper form published by O'Reilly, or as a PDF or HTML version online for free. This book teaches Python 3, and is used in colleges and universities the world over.

You don't have to switch immediately, the code taught in those first few chapters is mostly version agnostic. I think the book introduces the `print` statement on page 65, which in Python 3 is a function instead. I'd expect it to mostly stay away from the more problematic differences however.

Comment: Nice! 
I actually tried this first, but at the time I was using Python 3. So the differences between Python 3 and Python 2 are quite big then I see. Anyway, that solved it. thank you for this!

Comment: @KilgoreTrout33: the function, as defined, works just fine on Python 2 and 3. The differences are not *that* big, and a large number of libraries distributed on the Python package index (PyPI) can be used on both!

Comment: @KilgoreTrout33: I added some advice about options to learn Python 3 instead.

Comment: The last days of Python 2... That is very useful to know, considering the book. Thank you so much for the help and the recommendations!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def double(sequence): 
    result = [] #here starts the function body
    for element in sequence:
            result = result + [element * 2]
    return result
```

And then do `double([1, 10, 5])` to call the function.

The reason being that the function accepts *parameters* or *variables*, not *values*. Only when calling the function do you pass *values* to it